# Datatable rows come selected as default

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a datatable:

```
<p:dataTable style="width: 100%;" id="dTable" var="tt" value="#{backingBean.memberList}" paginator="true" rows="20" selection="#{backingBean.selectedMember}" selectionMode="single" onRowSelectUpdate="mf:tabcontent" onRowSelectComplete="tvl();">
```

whose rows come selected when the page loads. Does anyone have any opinion about this issue?
primefaces version is 2.2.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will happen if the array or collection behind `selection="#{backingBean.selectedMember}"` is been prefilled with the selected rows. If you set it to `null` or an empty array/collection, then nothing will be preselected.